# GTA V lost data XBOX 360

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I've been playing GTA V for 2 days now and I've restarted my Xbox 3 times without any data lost on my USB 16GB flashdrive.

And now I unplugged my Xbox-360 because I was going to move the TV and stuff so I could play GTA V more comfortable. And When I turned my Xbox on and GTA-v it started from 0%, I've done the game > load game things but my data is lost, I checked my system and the install files was still there on my USB stick. But not the quicksave. I quick saved 3 times before I unplugged the Xbox from the 220V wall outlet. And now I can't find the location where I saved everything.

Comment: Are you *definitely certain* you didn't turn off the console when that animated circle (the save icon) appeared on the lower right corner of the screen?

Comment: YEs I am sure, and even if I would have done it I'd have atleast the save before that save left?

Comment: Check the flashdrive on a PC, and check that you didn't save to another area, (I.E. Cloud, HDD, Flash drives on my system amount to four save areas.) If the flashdrive was where you were storing your games and your pc comes up with a drive that needs to be formatted then I would say that your drive could be toast and thus no more save. Google Data Recovery tools to see if you can save anything.

Comment: WHen you unplugged the xbox was the xbox on? The flashdrive can corrupt it's files by an un expected turn of the same way if you pull it out without ejecting it on the pc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this sounds crazy but make sure you're signed into the right profile - I stumbled across this post when I thought my save was gone until I realized I wasn't on the right one :P

Answer (score 0):

I think I made the same mistake with my profile but once I shut down and restarted in the correct profile it was fine.

Comment: This answer has almost identical content to the existing anonymous answer to this question which essentially boils down to "make sure you are using the correct profile." Could you perhaps try adding something beyond the existing answers? If you intended this as a comment on the other answer, gaining more reputation will enable you to comment on the answers/questions of others. If you agree with an existing answer, an upvote (also available with a little bit more reputation) would be the appropriate way to demonstrate this.